# Android Studio Parsing JSON object doesn't work

Tags: java, arrays, json

This is my json file. I am trying to load json in to my recyclerview, but after trying to get the array from the body object it runs on error.

```
{
body: {
posters: [
{
code: "3292d2r",
attributes: [
"12-plus-trailer",
"2d",
"adventure",
"dubbed",
"dubbed-lang-hu",
"fantasy"
],
featureTitle: "Artemis Fowl",
weight: 0,
dateStarted: "2020-05-28T00:00:00"
```

My java code:

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("body");
```

But this method doesn't work, any idea how I can get the items in posters to a JSONARRAY?
The JSON file structure:

```
{
body: {
posters: [
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{}
]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`body` is not a JSONArray. It is a JSONObject.

```
jsonObject.getJSONObject("body").getJSONArray("posters");
```